# Spring Data with RDS(Amazon web Service)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Can anyone please suggest whether we can perform crud operation on Amazon RDS using Spring Data.

Comment: try using spring CRUDRepositiory

Comment: Use CRUDRepository , you can refer this example [example](https://github.com/briansjavablog/spring-boot-aws)